# Minimum of a timestamp in a pandas dataframe at a row level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary having the keys and values of certain columns in the dataframe.

The values of the key hold the list of datetime. It could be NULL as well as hold datetime values.

I have to find the minimum within coalesce.

```
dt_columns = {
   "key1" : [value1, value2, value3, value4],
   "key2" : [value1, value2]
}
```

where `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `value4` are the columns of a dataframe for one row. `key1` will be a new column for the dataframe holding one value from the list.

```
value1 = '2023-06-05 09:30:21'
value2 = '2023-05-24 19:40:56'
value3 = None
value4 = None
```

`value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `value4` can hold either datetime or None.

The datatype of the values in the list is `datetime64` and `object` for None values.

In output it's required to return the minimum datetime from the list of values for the key.

I have tried multiple codes so far, but failed miserably. I have used `bfill` to coalesce the columns.

```
for col in coalesce_columns:
    #df[col] = df[dt_columns[col]].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].min()
    #df[col] = df[[dt_columns[col]]].min(axis=1, method='coalesce')
    #df[col] = min(df[dt_columns[col]].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
```

I'm getting the first date as the output for `key1`, i.e. `2023-06-05 09:30:21`. However the correct output should be `2023-05-24 19:40:56`.

How would this be accomplished (hopefully efficiently) in pandas?

Comment: What is `df` here?

Comment: @mozway `df` is very common shorthand for a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Michael very well aware, but OP should provide a reproducible example of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your approach. I would do the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
           "key1" : ['2023-06-05 09:30:21', '2023-05-24 19:40:56', None, None],
           "key2" : ['value1', 'value2',0,0]
    }
)

#convert to datetime and get the min value
r = pd.to_datetime(df.key1).min()

print(r)
#2023-05-24 19:40:56
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I have edited the question, It's seems like it was not much clear earlier.
the key1 is not the column in the dataFrame.

Comment: @spontaneous_coder It doesn't really matter. `pd.to_datetime()` can take arrays as well as input. Just pass the list of dates, and it will be fine.